# Object not found - XAMPP

Tags: html, apache, xampp

I recently installed XAMPP on my laptop - windows-7 64-bit. I just wrote a very basic and elementary "Hello World" script in HTML. But, however when i'm trying to run it, it says Object Not found. Error 404.

Here's what i'm doing:

1. Wrote the script.
2. Saved it as test.html in xampp/apache/htdocs.
3. Opened the browser, typed localhost/test.html in the space provided for the URL.

The bizarre thing is, i am able to run the index.html file stored in xampp/apache/htdocs. And i'm also able to run the localhost page. But any new page that i'm creating, i'm unable to run it. Please help me solve this problem.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems xampp is not able to locate your file.

Check DocumentRoot setting in XAMPP\apache\conf\httpd.conf to find currently it is pointing to which folder.

If you want you can point it to some other folder like,

D:/phpprojects/

By the way, You sure htdocs is in xampp/apache/htdocs ? Mine is in xampp/htdocs.

Comment: Hey, yeah actually there were two htdocs, one's just inside xampp and one's inside xampp/apache. When i saved my file to xampp/htdocs, it worked. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

if problem is in linux
Folders not should be cut from Windows into Linux
folders permissions not set . change it

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the root of project from **xampp/apache/htdocs** to **xampp/htdocs**.

I mean your project folder has to be in **xampp/htdocs** root .(e.g: `xampp/htdocs/project`).

And your project address will be `localhost/project`