# Object not found - XAMPP

Tags: xampp

I've not changed anything in my `xampp` recently, and it was working correctly until yesterday.

But now I got this error:

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3
```

I don't know what happened, because it was working until yesterday.

And also I have to say this address `localhost/phpmyadmin` work correctly, just my projects address like `localhost/project22` not working.

this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942229/xampp-object-not-found-error) and this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442119/object-not-found-xampp)  couldn't help me.

Comment: Any chance you have changed something in between? Apache conf., operating system, ..

Comment: @Hatef no I didn't

Comment: you tagged as php / mysql but there's no relevant code. Any `.htaccess` rules added? and is there an index file in the folder?

Comment: Directory permissions.Maybe user policy. Hosts file. Basic things. httpd.conf (not sure if it is still named like this in Xampp. Use Alias .

Comment: @Fred-ii- You are right it was wrong. it doesn't related. I removed tag. No it doesn't have `.htaccess` rule. yes there is `index` file. it not work for non of my projects.

Comment: Can I reinstall jus Apache ?

Comment: @user3344236 please explain more.

Comment: which windows you're using, are you putting this project22 in htdocs folder then you have to give this folder full control to the user. Easier if you give "Everyone" group .

Comment: @Mohtisham It isn't just for `localhost/project22`. This error shows when I type just `localhost` too. And of course `localhost folder` have `Everyone group` access.

Comment: project22 is in same folder as phpmyadmin ?? for which you mentioned that it is running correctly

Comment: @Mohtisham no, the root of **project22** folder is `C:\xampp\htdocs\project22` and the root of  **localhost** is `C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin`.

Comment: It seems that you have made change in conf file. And now your DocumentRoot is pointing to xampp folder. so you should move project22 into the xampp folder. or though it is not good but you could try this url http://localhost/htdocs/project22

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134889/discussion-between-mohtisham-and-mohammad-aghayari).

Comment: this seems to be settings for XAMPP, as no changes found in conf file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43107333/7871836 it's help me on my project.
Thank to Teik Fai .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally it got solved by adding an alias in XAMPP config file namely `httpd-xampp.conf`

```
Alias /project22 "C:/xampp/project22/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/project22">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

There were no changes, It seems to be some setting issue with XAMPP

Comment: But this works just for `index.php` page. for other pages not work.

Comment: the problem was because I've added some code for create subdomain in xampp few weeks ago. I removed the code and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Im not sure if it will work for you but you can try this method:

-Create a new .htaccess (if you have one) and put it on your project folder.

Then add the following code on it:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Then refresh your page.

Comment: Good solution. Worked fine for me in xampp / Mac

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error after changing my database name.
I used the search & replace plugin to change the old name to the new one but encountered the same error on all the pages except the home page.
All I did to solve this error was change the database name (on the .htaccess file) from the old one to the new one in between the codes above as in below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /"WRITE YOUR NEW DATABASE NAME HERE"/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
.
.
.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /"WRITE YOUR NEW DATABASE NAME HERE"/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got into this issue because I some how missed up xampp installation I have one xampp    installation `(c:/xampp)` and then I installed anther one inside it `(c:/xampp/xampp)`

so when I add file inside htdocs of the first xampp and I try to run it  but I discovered I run  second xammp so I got object not found!

to solve it quickly I added the php file in the second xampp installation path which is `c:/xampp/xampp/htdocs`

but generally you should have one xampp installation

> So check if you have installed  the server twice because that will make conflict if you add your file inside `htdocs` on a deferent running xampp path.

Answer (score 0):

config file namely `httpd-xampp.conf`

set root

```
Alias / "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```