# Image display from shared Drive on HTML page

Tags: html, xampp

Brief: I have a web-application and I want to link one more HTML page on its home page. That additional page has some images only. I am running the web application on XAMP web server. When I am putting the image files in same folder where HTML page is placed (C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectUI\html\img) its working fine.

Problem: Now I want to pick these images from one of the shared drive where other users can update the image with same name and it should be updated on the new page. I cannot give access of server to all the users, So I want to map a shared drive where they can update their image and it should be reflected on the page. I tried this on my own but HTML page couldn't read that path as it was looking the images in same folder.

Comment: Take a look at the `Alias` directive the apache http server offers.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable remarks. I'll take a look of this.

Comment: and how to add alias plz check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42042353/object-not-found-xampp/42051433?noredirect=1#comment71275991_42051433