# how to use rewrite url using htaccess for the following code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .htaccess

index to intermediate file is going well but it does not pass to statefinder file, please someone help me, its give error 'Object not found!' while the URL is right which are - 'bank-details/Abhyudaya-Cooperative-Bank-Limited'.
Please tell me what is I doing wrong

**index.php**

```php
<script>
$('#bank_name').change(function(){
    $('#form1').submit();
});
</script>

<?php
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
echo '<div id="div3">';
echo '<form id="form1" method="get" action="imtermediate1.php">';
echo '<img src="images/2.png" style="margin-left:30px">';
echo '<select id="bank_name" name="bank_name">';
echo '<option value="">SELECT BANK NAME</option>';
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    //echo $r['bank_name'];
    $name = $r['bank_name'];

    $name2 = explode(" ",$name);
    //$name3 = implode($name2,'.');
    $name5 = "";
    for($i = 0; $i<count($name2); $i++)
    {
        $name3 = $name2[$i];
        $name4 = ucfirst(strtolower($name3));
        $name5 .= $name4;
    }
    echo '<option value="'.$name5.'">'.$name.'</option>';
}
```

**imtermediate1.php**

```php
<?php 

    $name = $_GET['bank_name'];
    $pieces = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/',$name);
    $pieces2 = implode($pieces,"-");
    $piece3 = ltrim($pieces2,"-");
?>
<script>
    var name = "<?php echo $piece3;?>";
    window.location = "./" + name;
</script>
```

**statefinder.php**

```php
<script>
$('#state').change(function(){
    $('#form2').submit();
});
</script>

<?php
$name = $_GET['bank_name'];
$pieces = strtoupper($name);
$piece2 = explode("-",$pieces);
$piece3 = implode($piece2," ");

echo '<form id="form2" method="get" action="imtermediate2.php">';
echo '<img src="images/3.png"><select name="bank_name">';
echo '<option value="'.$name.'">'.$piece3.'</option>';
echo '</select><img src="images/4.png"><br>';
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT state FROM `TABLE 6` WHERE bank_name='$piece3' ORDER BY state ";
echo '<img src="images/2.png"><select name="state" id="state"><option>Select State Name</option>';
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
print_r($res);
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo '<option>'.$r['state'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select><img src="images/5.png"><br>';
echo '<img src="images/2.png" style="margin-left:-28px"><select><option>District</option></select><br>';
echo '<img src="images/2.png" style="margin-left:-28px"><select><option>Branch</option></select><br>';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Comment: I would imagine you get an error on your `$_GET['bank_name]` in statefinder.php, as you don't seen to be sending get variables with your `window.location = "./" + name;`

Comment: This user's problem could be similar to what you are encountering: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42042353/object-not-found-xampp

Comment: dear user Sl4rtib4rtf4st, this is used to set the URL- window.location = "./" + name;
my problem is that how we get the data in statefinder.php